# Write CSV file with JSON column has incorrect quote characters

Tags: python, csv

I am writing a new CSV file from a collection of data, which I would later like to import into a SQL database.

The data should be stored in JSON format in the 'size' and 'colors' columns.

How do I get the column to be enclosed in single quotes and the data within the brackets to be enclosed in double quotes?

```
with open("export.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    # Create a CSV writer using the field/column names
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        csvfile,
        fieldnames=csv_fields,
    )
    # Write the header row (column names)
    writer.writeheader()
    for key in dict_products:
        print(dict_products[key])
        writer.writerow(dict_products[key])
```

This is what is being created now.

```
id,prodcategory_id,name,featured,image_1,image_2,image_3,image_4,colors,sizes,article_number,price,manufacturer_id
NULL,521,,0,521010000-1.jpg,,,,['1'],"['39', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46']",521010000,6990,582
NULL,115,Women Court Sho,0,115130000-1.jpg,,,,['13'],"['36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41']",115130000,4990,32
```

That's how it should be:

```
id,prodcategory_id,name,featured,image_1,image_2,image_3,image_4,colors,sizes,article_number,price,manufacturer_id
NULL,521,,0,521010000-1.jpg,,,,["1"],'["39", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46"]',521010000,6990,582
NULL,115,Women Court Sho,0,115130000-1.jpg,,,,["13"],'["36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41"]',115130000,4990,32
```

Comment: It looks like the data you're writing out isn't actually JSON, (not that it's shown in the post...) so maybe a starting point would be: turn the list into a JSON string _first_. Then if you want to configure the quotes in CSV read the relevant docs.

Comment: Can you give an example of your Json?

Answer (score 0):

to me it looks like `dict_products` is a dictionary with a key and your desired csv rows as values.  the `colors` and `sizes` keys look like lists.  to get the quoted results you are seeking you need to use `json.dumps` on each value.  then when writing your csv, specify single quote (`'`) as the quote character.
https://onlinegdb.com/PBKLPNoar

```py
import csv, json


dict_products = {
'key1': {'id': 'NULL',
  'prodcategory_id': '521',
  'name': '',
  'featured': '0',
  'image_1': '521010000-1.jpg',
  'image_2': '',
  'image_3': '',
  'image_4': '',
  'colors': ['1'],
  'sizes': ['39', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46'],
  'article_number': '521010000',
  'price': '6990',
  'manufacturer_id': '582'},
'key2': {'id': 'NULL',
  'prodcategory_id': '115',
  'name': 'Women Court Sho',
  'featured': '0',
  'image_1': '115130000-1.jpg',
  'image_2': '',
  'image_3': '',
  'image_4': '',
  'colors': ['13'],
  'sizes': ['36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41'],
  'article_number': '115130000',
  'price': '4990',
  'manufacturer_id': '32'}
}
csv_fields = list(dict_products['key1'].keys())

with open("export.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        csvfile,
        fieldnames=csv_fields,
        quotechar='\''
    )
    writer.writeheader()
    for key in dict_products:
        color, sizes = dict_products[key]['colors'], dict_products[key]['sizes']
        dict_products[key]['colors'] = json.dumps(color)
        dict_products[key]['sizes'] = json.dumps(sizes)
        writer.writerow(dict_products[key])
```